# What is the Korean word for the type of melon (Cucumis melo) that has hair on the rind or hair on the peel?

Tags: food

### What is the Korean word for the cultivar of (오이 Cucumis melo) that has hair on the rind or hair on the peel?

---

### 오이의 피부에 머리카락이 달린 오이의 이름은 무엇입니까?

---

[image: FUZZY CUCUMBERS BARESE MELON]